# Faces move slow / not fully connected to bone

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, rigging, bones

Blend File:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B_GELU2WhmT1O25J6V82O1IMIik_EF1F

Good Morning,
I been having this problem for 2 days and I don't know how to fix it, I created a vertex group to control the eyelid of the spider with one bone, but it is not working properly, the edge is not following the bone as it should, it is moving slower, I just need to know if there's a way to make the edge be attached to the bone no matter what.

Also I don't like using shape keys because I need to do other stuff with the bone that the shape key won't work with
[image: the bone that is controlling the eyelid is the one with the shape of a triangle]
https://gyazo.com/b246445672450727703520960e55e3b2.gif

Comment: Just because vertexes are in the same vertex group does not mean they are equally weighted. Have you tried assigning them a weight or checking the weighting in the weight paint view?

Comment: Yes I've tried, the weight paint looks like this: https://gyazo.com/d990b2873a002ed8f6fc743bce74b240

I looked at other rigs and apparently they only have 2 colors on the weight paint, I asked a friend about my problem and he said to apply more weight but this is the max I can do, I don't know if I can set the weight values to be 0 or 1 (not middle values), Maybe that will fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the edge was also being controlled by another bone and by changing the weight of the other bones it worked